# Highcharts: X axis, MySQL datetime

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I cannot get highcharts to recognize my timestamps, they are in javascript date format.
Tried many different approaches, but cannot get it to work when both the data and time array's are seperate.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SjL6F/

```
    $(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ''
        }
    });


    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature - Last 24 hours',
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: "Test Site",
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            categories: time,
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e of %b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (\u00b0C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: temp,
            type: 'line',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' C'
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Highcharts just shows the raw javascript date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting categories, which isn't datetime type for xAxis. Remove them, then concat time and temp arrays.

For example:

```
var concatenatedData = [];
$.each(time, function(i, e){
        concatenatedData.push([parseInt(e), temp[i]]);
});
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/SjL6F/1/

Note: I have added parseInt, because Highcharts requires timestamps to be numbers, not strings.